# Git push: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

I am learning how to use Git + github.
I want to push my local repository to my git repository, I never did another one before.
With console I configured with the user.name .user.password user.email the same as the one in GitHub.
I created the local repository, I started git correctly, when I do `git push origin master` it asks me for username and password, I indicate them and it denies me access; After researching I found that I should create a token from my GH account, I created it, I tried the `git push origin master` and it denied me but this time it shows me the error: The requested URL returned error: 403

Try researching and entering the token; I hope you can tell me if I should make any configuration within my GH account or if I should modify the .config file

Comment: What scopes did you give your token?  Also, `user.password` doesn't exist (and the config file is not a secure place to put your credentials) and `user.name` should be a personal name (e.g., "Pat Doe") and has nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 auth options for `push`:

1. Personal Access Token (classic)¹ - needs `repo` scope. 
   Use the token value as the password
2. Fine-grained personal access token - needs `Contents` scope plus make sure you select the correct repository it applies to when creating it. 
   Use this as the password
3. Install [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) and then `$ gh auth login` which should open the web browser. 
   No explicit tokens here.

---

¹ There is some extra detail about https vs ssh but normally you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once. I generated a new token and put this in my Terminal :

```
git remote set-url origin https://<your personal token>@github.com/<your github 
username>/<your repo>
```

After that I was able to execute `git push -u origin main` (`master` in your case).